# Testing Boolean in Actionscript for null

Tags: actionscript, boolean

I have a Boolean variable in Actionscript 3.

How can I check if it's undefined (not by being false) because false is a value or Boolean in Actionscript is FALSE by default >

Comment: Boolean by definition means either true or false. If a Boolean variable is not assigned a value, as you mentioned, it is false by default. How about using a Number(which has NaN as the default value) ? Or an int with a set 'undefined' value you make up ? BTW, 0% accept for all those questions doesn't sound very encouraging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ActionScript, `Boolean` can have either `true` or `false` value only. If you don't specify any value, it is initialized to `false` by default.

Edit: This behavior is different from Java's `Boolean` object type which is a wrapper over primitive `boolean`. See @Victor's comments below

Comment: But in Java you get Null if you initialize the Boolean object

Comment: `Boolean` is a reference type wrapper for the `boolean` primitive type. Therefore, its *uninitialized* default value is `null`.

Comment: @SSF4Negative_Zero - but your question wasn't about Java; you can't expect all languages to work the same way.

Comment: Note that the comment from @VictorZamanian applies to Java not AS3

Comment: in flex is different. my experience is whatever strong you set the Boolean variable to null, it will be set to false by default.

Answer (score 12):

If you want a Boolean that can be undefined (essentially a tri-state flag), you can use an `Object` reference, but just assign the `Boolean` values `true` and `false` to it. Downside is that you lose the type safety.

```
var isSet:Object = null;
// Later...
isSet = true;
```

Comment: correct, whatever strong you to set the Boolean variable to null, it will be set to false by default. :)